# Knockout mapping adding a function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to add a function to a button on my form.  I keep getting a message that alertMe is undefined.

I've tried to declare my mapping as such:

```
$(function () {

        var mapping = {
            create: function (options) {
                return new CsvImportItem(options.data);
            },
            alertMe: function () {
                alert('Here we go');
            }
        }


        var CsvImportItem = function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

            this.rowClass = ko.computed(function () {
                if (this.Accepted()) return 'success'; else return 'error';
            }, this);

            this.acceptItem = function () {
                this.Accepted(true);
            };

            this.declineItem = function () {
                this.Accepted(false);
            };

        }
        var viewModelJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'), mapping);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModelJSON);
    });
```

If I change the viewModelJSON to :

```
var viewModelJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'), {}, mapping);
```

then the alertMe function call works, but the rest of my display items do not.  Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

**Update to show data structure**

My data structure coming in to the view is of type

```
IEnumberable<Project.Namespace.CsvImportItem>
```

Therefore, I am getting a structure like so:

```
[
 {CsvImportItem},
 {CsvImportItem},
 {CsvImportItem}
]
```

Comment: Why do you want the mapping to add the `alertMe`? Why do just put the `alertMe` definition on the `CsvImportItem` object?

Comment: I want the function to work on the collection of CsvImportItems, not on the instance of 1 CsvImportItem like my functions rowClass, acceptItem, and declineItem.  I'll update my post to make my data more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to apply the json mapping to the mapping object, correct syntax

```
var viewModelJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'), mapping);
```

Also skip the mapping, its not needed for simple scenarios like these just do

```
ko.applyBindings(new CsvImportItem($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)')));
```

Comment: The CsvImportItem is not the parent class, rather, my data is a collection of CsvImportItems that I've successfully declared functions for each instance( rowClass, acceptItem, and declineItem.  I'm trying to run a function on the entire collection of CsvImportItems, this is a precursor for me posting back the result set to my controller.

Comment: Okej, then you should do it like the first code example in my answer, your example code tries to map the JSON data to the mapping object which it wrong. ie replace {} with mapping

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am already calling the code `var viewModelJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)'), mapping);`  I just put the second way I tried as additional information.  For whatever reason, the alertMe works if I use the second code fragment, but nothing else works.  Strange.  I'm working on getting a fiddle put together.

Comment: Why do you have the alert on the mapping object? It should be there, the mapping object is just a helper object for the mapping plugin

Comment: It shouldn't be there, sorry for typo

Comment: I'm just missing how to get a function on the collection.  I'm trying to raise an alert just to see if it works, going to use a function to post back to my controller.  I've got a JSBin working as a test bed, I can't figure out how to add a function (in my test a simple alert) and bind it to the click of the submit button. http://jsbin.com/ijibim/1/edit

Comment: I think I just figured out my issue, updated my JSBin, http://jsbin.com/ijibim/2/edit , thanks for your help.  Next step for me is to post the data back.  I'm assuming that will work in place of the alert function.  Thanks.

Comment: To post it back you can just do ko.toJS, if you use jQuery for ajax post be sure to set the JSON dataformat on post otherwise jQuery will default to form post format which the MVC controller wont understand how to decode